# How to use wireless bridge with netgear router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

Initially I had a [Netgear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netgear_DG834_(series)) DG834 as my main home router. In order to connect wired devices I bought [DLink wireless N150 Bridge](http://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/d-link-dap-1155-n150-wireless-bridge-access-point-dldap1155)

There is WPS button on Dlink. Guide says to press WPS button and you have 120 seconds to press WPS on the router.

But I don't have WPS button on my Netgear router

Will this still work correctly?

This is my netgear config for bridging

[image]

Comment: WDS has nothing to do with WPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. WPS need to be supported by both device for it to work.

You have to configure your wireless bridge so it does not use WPS.

---

WPS (Wireless Protected Setup) is orthogonal to bridging.  It is just a security mechanism that wraps WPA2 into something aimed to be more user friendly.  If you do not use WPS, you can still configure WPA2 manually.

As for the bridging itself, there are several methods that can be used. the description of each method is maybe off-topic for this question. WDS is one of the method that can be used to bridge wired and wireless networks.  I do not know which method the wireless bridge use nor (in case of WDS) if the AP accepts four address frames by default.

Comment: ok so you mean . 1) i can still use bridge without WPS. 2. I don't need to do anything on netgear.